# Error prompt instead of prompt to re enter input

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, python-module

I am making a price is right game. I am currently working on a game mode similar to the contestant row, where they guess the price of an item.

When it asks you to submit a bid, if you enter a word (instead of a bid), the program crashes and displays the following error:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Thepriceisright.py", line 36, in 
>           contestantrow()
>         File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Thepriceisright.py", line 24, in contestantrow
>           protagnum=int(input(propername +", what is your bid?"))
>       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'alexei'"

Here's my code:

```
import random
print(" The Price is Sorta Right - 000776331")
welcomeplayer = True
contestantrow = True
def welcome():
    while True:
        global welcomeplayer
        global propername
        welcomeplayer =  input("Please enter your name using only letters")
        validname = welcomeplayer.isalpha()
        propername = welcomeplayer.capitalize()
        if validname == True:
            print( propername, " ! Come on down! You're the next contestant on the Price is (sorta) right")
            print (" Dew Drop welcomes " ,propername ," to contestants row joining EIMNOT A. HUMAN,ARTHURFICIAL EINTEL , ROBORT")
            return
        else:
            print("Please only write letters on your name tag")
            welcomeplayer = False

def contestantrow():
    while True:

        print("Dew Drop shows the price that you are bidding on")
        protagnum=int(input(propername +", what is your bid?"))
        if protagnum > 0:
            componebid = random.randint(1,1000)
            print("EIMNOT A. HUMAN bids: ",componebid)
            comptwobid = random.randint(1,1000)
            print("ARTHURFICIAL EINTEL bids: ",comptwobid)
            compthreebid =random.randint(1,1000)
            print("ROBORT bids: ",compthreebid)
        else:
            print(" Dew Drop says [Im sorry bids should start at atleast one dollar]")
            contestantrow = False
welcome()
contestantrow()
```

Comment: Use a Try/Exception block around that block of code to catch the exception ValueError and ask for another input

Answer (score 0):

```
protagnum=int(input(propername +", what is your bid?"))
```

You're converting an int / string to int. "1" will work but "a" will raise a ValueError

```
while True:
    try:
        protagnum=int(input(propername +", what is your bid?"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid bid, please try again")
```

Comment: I tried it that and when I entered string an error popped up. I kept the if protagnum > 0 part because the bid has to be at least 1 dollar and it cant be a text.